# Getting Identity ID from new record in RIA Services

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm, wcf-ria-services

I've seen a lot of articles about retrieving the identity ID of a new created record using other DBs and frameworks. I am creating a record in code in a Silverlight RIA Services app. I perform the Add method and then do a SubmitChanges on the DomainContext, but I do not see the ID. It comes up as 0. How do I get the new ID? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
private void OnProfileCreateCallback(SubmitOperation submitOperation)
        {
          submitOperation.ChangeSet.AddedEntities.First().GetIdentity()
        ....
        }
```

OnProfileCreateCallback is a call back method used in context.submitchanges(...)

You can put custom logic if you are having multiple records as part of add.